# Numlock в Manjaro XFCE

Tags: linux, manjaro, xfce

Моя проблема в том, что numlock при включении компьютера выключен, но это ещё пол беды. При смене пользователя он вдобавок дико глючит и чтобы его потом включить, нужно нажать как минимум 3 раза.

Когда-то давно мне помогала [эта инструкция](https://antergos.com/wiki/desktops/numlock-on-at-login-screen/), но сейчас она уже не актуальна (я не знаю почему, такое чувство, будто lightdm.conf вообще игнорируется).

Кроме того, **ничего** из [этой инструкции](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Activating_Numlock_on_Bootup) также не помогает!

После установки пакета `systemd-numlockontty` и включения его сервиса, заметно что намлок таки включается после загрузки компьютера, но тут же выключается при входе в дисплей-менеджер. Я даже пробовал ставить другие DM, это также не помогло.